# Going nuts trying to get JQuery enable in an ROR application

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to enable JQuery on an ROR (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3.p0) application I'm working on.  I've installed the jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails gems, bundle install, rails generate jquery:install and tested both with the javascript/css include tags as well as turning pipelining off and just dumping the files in public\javascripts.

I'm able to run the jquery test page from http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/, section "*Basic overview: using jQuery UI on a web page*".

Off an Apache server on the same box/different port with no problems, so not a browser issue.  I modified one of my model#index pages to just render the same jquery test page, but still no joy.  Could it be a WEBrick issue?  the WEBrick logs show the .js files (including the jquery.js file) being retrieved with a 304 Not Modified.  Is there a way to enhance WEBrick logging to show the webpage focus events?

I've read that jquery on Rails 3.2 should run with no javascript/css_include_tag modifications,

Comment: Really need more information about the failure mode.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  What error, if any, do you see?  What does "just render the same jquery test page" mean in the context of a controller action?

Comment: With the referenced test page, you get a set of functioning jquery controls.  With Apache, when I copy the JQuery css and js files to the appropriate htdocs folder, I render the test page and voila, all the test controls work.   When attempting the same in ROR using javascript_include_tags and/or putting the JQuery css and js files in assets/{javascript|css} or public/{javascript|css}, it fails to enable the test controls.

Comment: Rails won't correctly render any given webpage outside the context of a Rails app.  Try putting the test controls into a view and the associated jQuery into the corresponding file in app/assets/javascripts.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did - I modified my model controller to render "{model}#test_page" instead of the desired page and put the jquery css and js files in the appropriate locations.  The jquery css and js files are getting loaded correctly as per the WEBrick logs, but it's as if ROR can't find the js and css files when rendering.

Comment: I recommend posting much more information.  Post relevant portions of the models, views, js, controllers, Gemfile, and the logs.

Comment: Post want your application.css and application.js directives look like

Comment: Here we go - this is for a Veterinary Mgmt application...
  I took the model and controller for the person model and modified the controller to load up the jquery test page.  I then modified the application.rb to include the javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag.

Comment: This is for a Veterinary Mgmt application...
    
     I took a working model and controller for the person model and modified the controller#index method to render the jquery test page instead of the default people/show page.  I then modified the application.rb to include the javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag. 
   Firefox Firebug shows that the HTML rendering from ROR is working as I see the js files and css scripts in the page source. 

   Is there a way to attach files?  I'll copy all the files to a zipfile and upload them. 

Thanks! - Lenny

Answer (score 0):

Indeed in rails 3.2 you dont need additional gems for jquery.
From gems you only need

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**and your are ready to go**

in your layout just add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> #includes the main .js | .coffee file
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery      -> Imports jquery to asset
//= require jquery_ujs  
//= require_tree .      -> Imports an js or coffee file in pipe
```

All those with enabled asset pipeline, in case you **dont want to use asset pipeline**(please use it) *download jquery file add it to vendors javascripts* and call it with javascript_include_tag  .